# Flat tow 1988 Mazda RX7? Is it safe to do without disconnecting driveshaft or making other changes?

Tags: mazda

Is it safe to flat tow 1988 RX7 manual transmission?

Answer (score 2):

Generally manual transmission vehicles are safe to tow but, as always, consult your owners manual for details.

Comment: Ensure it's out of gear if it does get towed.